# Why does only half of my button work?

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons on a site i am making, but when i make the buttons wider they get wider, but only the first half of them are clickable and i dont know what the problem is?

This is the javascript code and i don't think that's the problem.

```
// this is where the main JavaScript and some jQuery runs to make the site work

// variable with your'e money
var money = 0;
var totalTimesClicked = 0;


// Hide all buttons
$("#but1").hide();
$("#but2").hide();
$("#but3").hide();
$("#but4").hide();
$("#but5").hide();
$(".codeLines").hide();

// function used to generate money
function getmoney(income) {
    money = money + income;
}

// automatically makes money untill 100 money
window.setInterval(function(){
    if (money < 100) {
        getmoney(0.1);
    }
// automatically makes money untill 500 money
    else if (money > 100 && money < 500) {
        getmoney(0.05)
    }
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.round(money*10)/10;
}, 100)

// make the click to make money button appear when you have more money than 10
var buldings1_appear = setInterval(function(){
if (money >= 9) {
$("#but1").slideDown("slow");
}
// make the auto income button appear when you have more money than 20
if (money >= 20) {
$("#but4").slideDown("slow");
}
},1000)

var clickEffect = 1;
// the click to make money function

$("#but1").click(function(){
    getmoney(clickEffect);
    totalTimesClicked = totalTimesClicked + clickEffect;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.round(money*10)/10;
        document.getElementById("totalTimesClicked").innerHTML = totalTimesClicked;
$("#but2").slideDown("slow");
});

// make more money by clicking on button 1
var clicks = 0;
$("#but2").click(function(){
    var cost = 50;
    var multiplyBut1Cost = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.3,clicks));
    if (money >= multiplyBut1Cost) {
        money = money -  multiplyBut1Cost;
        clickEffect = clickEffect + 1;
        clicks = clicks + 1;    
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.round(money*10)/10;
    document.getElementById("clickEffect").innerHTML = clickEffect;
    if (clicks >= 5) {
$("#but3").slideDown("slow");
    }
}
var multiplyBut1NextCost = Math.floor(cost * (Math.pow(1.3, clicks)));
    document.getElementById("multiplyBut1Cost").innerHTML=multiplyBut1NextCost;

})

var but3clicks = 0;
$("#but3").click(function(){
    var cost = 1000;
    var multiplyBut1Cost2 = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.2, but3clicks));
    if (money >= multiplyBut1Cost2) {
        money = money -  multiplyBut1Cost2;
        clickEffect = clickEffect + 5;
        but3clicks = but3clicks + 1;    
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.round(money*10)/10;
    document.getElementById("clickEffect").innerHTML = clickEffect;
}
var multiplyBut1NextCost = Math.floor(cost * (Math.pow(1.3, but3clicks)));
    document.getElementById("multiplyBut1Cost2").innerHTML=multiplyBut1NextCost;

})

var effect = 0.1;
var but4income = 0;
var but4bought = 0;
var but4spawned = 0;
function buyBut4(){
    var cost = 25;
    var but4cost = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.2,but4bought));
        if(money>=but4cost){
        but4bought = but4bought+1;
        money = money - but4cost;
        but4income = (but4bought + but4spawned) * effect;
        document.getElementById("but4bought").innerHTML = but4bought;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
if (but4bought >= 5) {
    $("#but5").slideDown("slow");
}

}
    var nextCost = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.2,but4bought));
    document.getElementById("but4cost").innerHTML = nextCost;
};

setInterval(function(){
    getmoney((but4bought + but4spawned) * effect)
document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = Math.round(money*10)/10;

},100)

var but5effect = 0.001;
var but5bought = 0;
var but5income = 0;
function buyBut5(){
    var cost = 1000;
    var but5cost = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.4,but5bought));
        if(money>=but5cost){
        but5bought = but5bought+1;
        money = money - but5cost;
        but5income = but5bought * but5effect;
        document.getElementById("but5bought").innerHTML = but5bought;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = money;
        document.getElementById("but5income").innerHTML = Math.round(but5income * 1000)/100;
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(cost*Math.pow(1.4,but5bought));
    document.getElementById("but5cost").innerHTML = nextCost;
};

setInterval(function(){
    but4spawned = but4spawned + but5bought * but5effect; 
    but4income = (but4bought + but4spawned) * effect;
    document.getElementById("but4spawned").innerHTML = Math.round(but4spawned*10)/10;
    document.getElementById("but4income").innerHTML = Math.round(but4income * 100)/10;
},100)





 Window.onload = function supportsLocalStorage() {
      try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
      } catch(e){
        return false;
      }
    }

function saveGame(){
    localStorage.setItem('money', JSON.stringify(money));
}

function loadGame(){
    money = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('money'))
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('money'))
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("money");
}

function makeMoneySite(){
    $(".buildings").show("slow");
    $(".upgrades").hide("slow");
}

function upgradesSite(){
    $(".buildings").hide("slow");
    $(".upgrades").show("slow");
}

// Window.onload(loadGame());
```

Here is the css and i think the problem could be here

```
h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.resources ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:18px;
}

.tabs ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5%;
    position: relative;
}

.saveButton ul{
    padding: 5%;
    width: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.buildings ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}


.buildings button {
    width: 300px;
    height: 64px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.buildings button .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;

    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.buildings button:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Or maybe the problem is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Increment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- the header -->
<h1> U will automatically gain 1 money untill you have 100 money and 0.5 money between 200 and 500 money </h1>

<!-- the class with the resources u need to play the game -->
<div class="resources">
<ul>
    <li> Money <span id="money"> 0 </span></li>
    <li> Money made by clicking <span id="totalTimesClicked"> 0 </span></li>
    <li class="codeLines"> Lines of code <span id="linesOfCode"> 0</span></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
<ul>
<li onclick="makeMoneySite()"> Buildings</li>
<li onclick="upgradesSite()"> Upgrades </li>
<li> Prestige </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="saveButton">
<ul>
    <li> <button onclick="saveGame()"> Save your progress</button> </li>
    <li> <button onclick="loadGame()"> Load a previous game</button> </li>
</ul>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<!-- class with the first row of buttons -->
<div class="buildings">
<ul class="clickerBuildings">
<!-- the click to make money button with the tooltip inside of it -->
    <li>
        <button id="but1"> Click here to make money <p class="tooltiptext">By clicking here u make <span id="clickEffect"> 1 </span> money per click</p></button>
    </li>

<!-- the button to make the click button more effecient with the tooltip inside of it -->
    <li>
        <button id="but2"> Make the click button better <p class="tooltiptext"> Click here to make 1 more money per click on the click button above at the cost of <span id="multiplyBut1Cost"> 50 </span> money </p></button>
    </li>

<!-- the button to make the click button super effecient with the tooltip inside -->
    <li>
        <button id="but3"> Make the click button even better! <p class="tooltiptext"> Click here to make 5 more money per click on the click button above at the cost of <span id="multiplyBut1Cost2"> 1000 </span> money </p> </button>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul class="autoincome">
    <li>
        <button id="but4" onclick="buyBut4()"> Click this to make automatic income <p class="tooltiptext">The automatic income costs <span id="but4cost"> 25 </span> <br> You have bought <span id="but4bought">0 </span> automatic income machines and spawned <span id="but4spawned"> 0 </span> but4's <br> But4 total income <span id="but4income"> 0</span> per second</p></button>
    </li>

    <li>
        <button id="but5" onclick="buyBut5()"> Click here to spawn but4's <p class="tooltiptext"> The but5 costs <span id="but5cost"> 1000 </span> <br>Your <span id="but5bought"> 0 </span> but5's spawns <span id="but5income"> 0 </span> but4's per second </p></button>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>







<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The button will appear when u have 10 money

Comment: Please work on paring your code example down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here, and a lot of issues. But the **reason** some buttons appear non-clickable is because you have "messed up" structuring and styling.

Your `saveButton` element contains solely an `absolute`ly positioned element (thus this parent doesn't clear and sits on top of the "big button" parent element) , which has child elements (`li`) that are `block` positioned and "overflowing" of the "big buttons" clickable area.

Honestly, there's so many issues going over each one would take way too long.

To resolve your "click" issue you have a few options:

1. For the big buttons, add `position: relative; z-index: 99` or any higher `z-index` value - this could screw up z positioning of your elements however.
2. For the `.saveButton ul` element, remove the `position: absolute`
3. For the `.saveButton ul > li` elements, add `display: inline-block`

Any *one* of those will resolve your issue, but I highly recommend re-evaluating your `html` structuring and `css` styling.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1amfuot/1/)** using one of the above mentioned techniques.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your positioning of `ul` which houses the **Save Game** and **Load a previous game** links.

```
<ul>
  <li> <button onclick="saveGame()"> Save your progress</button> </li>
  <li> <button onclick="loadGame()"> Load a previous game</button></li>
</ul>
```

The unordered list is overlaid on the buttons. In the image below, you can see the boundary of the unordered list and it stays on top of the buttons. That is why you're unable to click the top four buttons properly.

[image]

To fix this, position your `ul` properly. I would suggest you to change the structure of your page first. Remove the absolute position on the `ul` element if you're okay with it. Without removing the `position:absolute`, a temporary fix would be

```
.saveButton ul{
    margin-top:20%;
}
```

Note: If you use Inspect Element in the Developer Tools, you can find the boundary of every DOM element.